# Problems with running a PHP file to include directories via Linux?

Tags: linux, php, cron

I'm running a Centos 5 server and want to set up a cronjob to run on every 10th of each month, but I have to following concern.

The PHP file that I need to run sits in `/var/www/html/test/` called `sendMails.php`

If I go to the test directory eg. `cd /var/www/html/test` and type in `./sendMails.php` my script runs perfect.

In the test directory is a folder called template and in the template folder is a file with the name `index.htm`. `index.htm` is being read in `sendMails.php` via the php function `file_get_contents` .

Now I run the script from my home directory eg. `php /home/roland/sendMails.php` and I get the following error `file_get_contents(template/index.htm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` and don't understand why, now this will then also fail if I setup a cron.

Any advise will be appreciated

Comment: Please if down voting this question at least tell me why????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you moved the template directory too?

You are better to put the files somewhere and make the script your absolute paths. 
E.g. /path/to/your/script.php
and in the script
include(/path/to/your/include/dir/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

As already said its better to use absolute path.

I think i**t is not good to hardcode the absolute path in each script**, at least if there is no real necessity. This is a strong portability limit.

The right way is to **calculate the absolute path at runtime** using **dirname(__FILE__)** to retrieve the dir of the current script (the script itself, not the includer of the script if it exists)

In your case you can do

```
<?php
#Sendmail.php

file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/template/index.htm')
?>
```

This has to work, everywhere!

Comment: +1 was going to suggest using ``dirname(__FILE__)`` myself but you beat me too it...

Comment: eheh, tnx Jeremy

Comment: Agreed.  `dirname(__FILE__)` is the best way to do this

Answer (score -1):

Create a shell script that changes directory and runs the php script; then call this shell script from cronjob.

Comment: Why not to create a cronjob that one per year creates that shell script? Next years doing nothing having already done the job! ;P

Answer (score -1):

You can add "chdir('/var/www/blabla');" at the top of your PHP file.

Comment: very tricky and inelegant to me

Comment: I agree, this should be avoided. Unfortunately, it's sometimes necessary when using an include tree that makes assumptions about file locations.